# Current status of nonextensive statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

A version of the maximum entropy principle is the following.

$$\max_{P}~~~ -\sum_i p_i\log p_i$$
subject to all probability distributions $P=\{p_i\}$ satisfying $$\sum_i p_i \epsilon_i = U.$$

Tsallis proposed the following extension of the maximum entropy principle (called non-extensive statistical mechanics).

$$\max_{P}~~~ \sum_i \frac{1-p_i^{\alpha}}{\alpha -1}$$
subject to all probability distributions $P=\{p_i\}$ satisfying $$\sum_i \frac{p_i^{\alpha}}{\sum_j p_j^{\alpha}} \epsilon_i = U^{(\alpha)}.$$

Sometime back I was bit following some of the papers in this area. There were papers supporting this principle and some were criticizing it. I also asked some questions regarding this non-extensive statistical mechanics in this forum before.

Can someone explain the recent developments in this area? We have some mathematical results in this direction. So, wondering whether publishing them now  would have any current relevance in this field.

Comment: George Livadiotis has done a bunch of work on this and "clarified" several misconceptions or misuses of the so called _q-distribution_ that Tsallis derived.  So far as I can tell from reading George's work is that the natural state of a collisionless (or weakly collisional) plasma is a kappa velocity distribution.  In the limit of zero particle-particle correlations, $\kappa \rightarrow \infty$ which is equivalent to the more well known Maxwellian.  Electromagnetic waves produce correlations resulting in $\kappa \sim 3--5$ in the solar wind.

Comment: It is well and alive, see for instance http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.91.052112